# Загружает ли браузер картинку заново при подмене атрибута src для img?

Tags: javascript

Загружает ли браузер картинку заново при подмене атрибута src для img?

Есть галерея, в которой при наведении на уменьшенную картинку, она появляется в блоке с большим размером. Работает она заменой src для img, как это влияет на производительность?

Пример работы: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/jGzOyQ

Просит выложить html, поэтому выкладываю для модерации вопроса, никакого смысла не несет

```
<div class="product__slider">
  <div class="product__slider-photo">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841024/v841024287/1c91c/h8XGWuDBjn8.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="0">
  </div>
  <div class="product__slider-nav">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c841024/v841024287/1c91c/h8XGWuDBjn8.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="0">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c639816/v639816421/38089/GjCdk2X_ifI.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="1">
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837433/v837433282/4d8fe/UEbY-oQHoD4.jpg" alt="51 роза" data-id="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если картинка уже в кеше, то не грузит заново.

Comment: Самое логичное было - проверить в инструментах разработчика вкладку "Network" там отображается все что загружается. Что же касается вопроса, как и сказано выше, если картинка уже загрузилась, то повторно она будет подгружаться из кэша.